# Configuring multiple databases in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

## Introduction

I have read [Django docs: Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/), but it doesn't seem to work for me after upgrading from 3.2 to 4.0. Other changes have been made, but since I'm working in a development environment, I chose to remove all previous migrations and run `./manage.py makemigrations` again, but it did not help to solve the issue.

## Router Definition

First, here's how I define the router. You'll notice it's nearly identical to the example, but I include mostly everything in the `admin_db` database (with two exceptions: custom apps `api.dictionary` and `api.pdf`).

*/api/authentication/routers.py*

```py
class AdminDBRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the authentication application, all and any dependent applications, and Django administrative applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {
        'admin',
        'auth',
        'authentication',
        'contenttypes',
        'sessions',
        'sites',
        'token_blacklist',
    }

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read models defined in any app in 'self.route_app_labels' go to 'admin_db'.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'admin_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write models defined in any app in 'self.route_app_labels' go to 'admin_db'.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'admin_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in any app defined in 'self.route_app_labels' is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or \
           obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure any app in 'self.route_app_labels' only appears in the 'admin_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'admin_db'
        return None
```

## Settings

And here's how I set up the apps/databases in settings:

*/project_name/settings.py*

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api',
    'api.authentication',
    'api.dictionary',
    'api.pdf',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_smtp_ssl',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': DEFAULT_DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'TEST': {
            'DEPENDENCIES': ['admin_db'],
        },
    },
    'admin_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': ADMIN_DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': ADMIN_DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': ADMIN_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'TEST': {
            'DEPENDENCIES': [],
        },
    },
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['api.authentication.routers.AdminDBRouter']
```

## Making Migrations

As stated earlier, I ran `makemigrations`. Here's the command output:

```sh
(.venv) arch-laptop back-end > ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'dictionary':
  api/dictionary/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Category
    - Create model MP3
    - Create model Word
    - Create model ThesaurusEntry
    - Create model Icon
    - Create model DictionaryEntry
Migrations for 'pdf':
  api/pdf/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Category
    - Create model PDF
Migrations for 'authentication':
  api/authentication/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
```

…and here are the files it generated:

*/api/authentication/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```py
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-03-01 21:18

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(default=None, max_length=64, unique=True, verbose_name='username')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(default=None, max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='is active')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='is staff')),
                ('is_verified', models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='is verified')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

*/api/dictionary/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```py
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-03-01 21:18

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('parent', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='children', to='dictionary.category')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Categories',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MP3',
            fields=[
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('mp3', models.FileField(upload_to='mp3', verbose_name='MP3')),
                ('_hash', models.BinaryField(max_length=16, null=True, verbose_name='MD5 hash')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Word',
            fields=[
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ThesaurusEntry',
            fields=[
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('json', models.TextField(default='', verbose_name='Merriam-Webster thesaurus entry')),
                ('mp3', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='dictionary.mp3')),
                ('word', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='dictionary.word')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Icon',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('image', models.ImageField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, upload_to='img')),
                ('_hash', models.BinaryField(max_length=16, null=True, verbose_name='MD5 hash')),
                ('word', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('descriptor', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=80, null=True)),
                ('is_approved', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('category', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='dictionary.category')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='DictionaryEntry',
            fields=[
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('id', models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('json', models.TextField(default='', verbose_name='Merriam-Webster dictionary entry')),
                ('mp3', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='dictionary.mp3')),
                ('word', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='dictionary.word')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

*/api/pdf/migrations/0001_initial.py*

```py
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-03-01 21:18

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='Name')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PDF',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='datetime created')),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='datetime updated')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Title')),
                ('pdf', models.FileField(max_length=160, upload_to='pdf', verbose_name='PDF')),
                ('_hash', models.BinaryField(max_length=16, null=True, verbose_name='MD5 hash')),
                ('categories', models.ManyToManyField(to='pdf.category')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

## Running Migrations

**This is where I encounter the issue.**

```sh
(.venv) arch-laptop back-end > ./manage.py migrate --database=admin_db --fake
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authentication, contenttypes, dictionary, pdf, sessions, sites, token_blacklist
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... FAKED
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... FAKED
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... FAKED
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... FAKED
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... FAKED
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying authentication.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... FAKED
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... FAKED
  Applying dictionary.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying pdf.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sites.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0002_outstandingtoken_jti_hex... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0003_auto_20171017_2007... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0004_auto_20171017_2013... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0005_remove_outstandingtoken_jti... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0006_auto_20171017_2113... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0007_auto_20171017_2214... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0008_migrate_to_bigautofield... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0010_fix_migrate_to_bigautofield... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0011_linearizes_history... FAKED
(.venv) arch-laptop back-end > ./manage.py migrate --database=default --fake
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authentication, contenttypes, dictionary, pdf, sessions, sites, token_blacklist
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... FAKED
  Applying auth.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... FAKED
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... FAKED
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... FAKED
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... FAKED
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... FAKED
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... FAKED
  Applying authentication.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... FAKED
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... FAKED
  Applying dictionary.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying pdf.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sites.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0002_outstandingtoken_jti_hex... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0003_auto_20171017_2007... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0004_auto_20171017_2013... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0005_remove_outstandingtoken_jti... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0006_auto_20171017_2113... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0007_auto_20171017_2214... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0008_migrate_to_bigautofield... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0010_fix_migrate_to_bigautofield... FAKED
  Applying token_blacklist.0011_linearizes_history... FAKED
```

## Summary

As you can see, both databases get *all* changes applied to them. I tried setting breakpoints and print statements in the router methods, but the correct values were being returned. The strange thing is I had it working when it was just the `authentication` and `dictionary` apps, but once I introduced the `pdf` app, I started having issues. What can I try?